# Prove inequality $\tan \left( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}\right) \tan \left( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)\le\frac13 $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

How to determine the range of the function

$$f(x)=\tan \left( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)
\tan \left( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)
$$

It it is straightforward to verify that $f(x)$ is even and

$$f(0)= \frac13, \>\>\>\>\> \lim_{x\to\pm \infty} f(x) \to -\infty$$

which implies $f(x) \in (-\infty,\frac13]$, i.e.

$$\tan \left( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)
\tan \left( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)\le \frac13
$$

and is visually confirmed below

[image]

However, it is not obvious algebraically that $f(x)$ monotonically decreases away from $x=0$. The standard derivative tests are not viable due to their rather complicated functional forms.

So, the question is how to prove the inequality  $f(x) \le \frac13$ with rigor.

Note that it is equivalent to proving

$$\cot \left(\frac{\pi(1+x)}{3+x^2}\right)
\cot \left(\frac{\pi(1-x)}{3+x^2}\right)\le \frac13
$$

Comment: It might happen that in a function with similar conclusions will have: $g(\pm1)>\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: We need to prove the case $0\le x < 1$ (the other cases are easy). (Inspired by @pisoir's 1st equation) Let $A =  \frac\pi2 \frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}, B = \frac\pi2 \frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}$.
It suffices to prove that $\sin A \sin B \le \frac{1}{3}\cos A \cos B$ or
$\frac{1}{2}[\cos (A - B) - \cos ( A + B)] \le \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}[\cos (A - B) + \cos (A + B)]$
or
$$\cos \frac{2\pi x}{x^2 + 3} \le 2 \cos \frac{\pi (x^2 + 1)}{x^2 + 3}. $$ The remaining is smooth.

Comment: @RiverLi - I’m not sure it is easier to show $\cos \frac{2\pi x}{x^2+3} \le 2\cos \frac{\pi (x^2+1)}{x^2+3} $. Can you expand?

Comment: @Quanto I want to see if pisoir has a nice solution. If no, I will post mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $f(1) \triangleq
\lim_{x\to 1} \tan ( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2})
\tan ( \frac\pi2 \frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}) = 0$.

Since $f(x)$ is even, we only need to prove the case $x \in [0, \infty)$.
Clearly $f(x) < 0$ for all $x > 1$. Also, $f(1) = 0$.
Thus, we only need to prove the case $0\le x < 1$.

(Inspired by @**pisoir**'s 1st equation) Let $A =  \frac\pi2 \frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}, B = \frac\pi2 \frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}$.
Clearly $A, B \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.
It suffices to prove that $\sin A \sin B \le \frac{1}{3}\cos A \cos B$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}[\cos (A - B) - \cos ( A + B)] \le \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}[\cos (A - B) + \cos (A + B)]$$
or
$$\cos \frac{2\pi x}{x^2 + 3} \le 2 \cos \frac{\pi (x^2 + 1)}{x^2 + 3}. $$

Let $C = \frac{2\pi x}{x^2 + 3}$ and $D = \frac{\pi (x^2 + 1)}{x^2 + 3}$.

We split into two cases:

1. $\frac{1}{3} \le x < 1$:

Clearly, $\frac{\pi}{3} \le D \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 \le \frac{\pi}{2} - C \le 2(\frac{\pi}{2} - D) \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. We have
\begin{align}
\cos C &= \sin (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - C) \\
&\le \sin [2(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - D)]\\
&= 2\sin (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - D) \cos (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - D) \\
&\le 2\sin (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - D) \\
&= 2\cos D.
\end{align}

2. $0 \le x < \frac{1}{3}$:

We give the following auxiliary results (Facts 1-2). The proofs are easy and thus omitted.

*Fact 1*: $\cos u \le 1 - \frac{1}{3}u^2$ for all $u$ in $[0, \pi/4]$.

*Fact 2*: $\cos v \ge \frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{9}\sqrt{3}\, (v - \tfrac{\pi}{3})$ for all $v \in [\pi/3, \pi/2]$.

Let us proceed. Clearly $C \in [0, \pi/4]$ and $D \in [\pi/3, \pi/2]$.
By Facts 1-2, it suffices to prove that
$$1 - \frac{1}{3}C^2 \le
2\left[\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{9}\sqrt{3}\, \left(D - \frac{\pi}{3}\right)
\right]$$
that is
$$\frac{4\pi x^2 [9\pi - 5\sqrt{3}(x^2 + 3)]}{27(x^2 + 3)^2}\ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not too hard if you consider
$$f(x)=\tan (A(x))\,\tan (B(x))$$ Using logarithmic differentiation
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=A'(x) \csc (A(x)) \sec (A(x))+B'(x) \csc (B(x)) \sec (B(x))$$

This gives $f'(0)=0$.

Repeating the process knowing that $f(0)=\frac 13$ and $f'(0)=0$ (this simplifies a lot the calculations), we have
$$f''(0)=\frac{16}{81} \left(\sqrt{3}-\pi \right) \pi <0$$ So, by the second derivative test $x=0$ corresponds to the maximum of the function.

We could also have composed Taylor series around $x=0$ to obtain
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{81} \left(\sqrt{3}-\pi \right) \pi  x^2+\frac{8 \pi 
   \left(\pi  \left(27+2 \sqrt{3} \pi -3 \pi ^2\right)-9 \sqrt{3}\right)
   }{2187}x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$ which a perfect approximation of the function for $-\frac 12 \leq x \leq \frac 12$ (maximum error  $< 0.00012$ at the bounds).

Comment: I think you just showed $f(0)$  is a local maxima. How do you show it is global as well, i.e. $f(x)\le\frac13$ over $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: @Quanto. I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(1-x)^2}{3+x^2}\right)=\frac{2\cos(2\pi/(3+x^2))}{\cos(2\pi x/(3+x^2))-\cos(2\pi/(3+x^2)} +1,$$
which is slightly easier to take the derivative:

$$f'(x)=\frac{8 \pi x \cos(\frac{2 \pi x}{3 + x^2}) \sin(\frac{2 \pi}{3 + x^2}) - 4 \pi (x^2-3) \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{3 + x^2}) \sin(\frac{2 \pi x}{3 + x^2})}{(3 + x^2)^2 \left(\cos(\frac{2 \pi}{3 + x^2}) - \cos(\frac{2 \pi x}{3 + x^2})\right)^2}$$

Obviously the denominator is positive, so we need to show that for $x \geq  0$:
$$8 \pi x \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi x}{3 + x^2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi}{3 + x^2}\right) - 4 \pi (x^2-3) \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{3 + x^2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi x}{3 + x^2}\right) \leq 0.$$

This can be further simplified to
$$-2 \pi \left((x-1)(x+3) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi(x-1)}{3 + x^2}\right) + (x+1)(x-3) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi(x+1)}{3 + x^2}\right)\right)\leq 0\tag{1}$$
ant thus we need to show that for $x\geq 0$
$$(x-1)(x+3) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi(x-1)}{3 + x^2}\right) \geq -(x+1)(x-3) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi(x+1)}{3 + x^2}\right)$$
<strike>It [seems](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288%20Pi%20x%20Cos%5B%282%20Pi%20x%29%2F%283%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%5D%20Sin%5B%282%20Pi%29%2F%283%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%5D%20-%204%20Pi%20%28-3%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%20Cos%5B%282%20Pi%29%2F%283%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%5D%20Sin%5B%282%20Pi%20x%29%2F%283%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%5D%29) we have to split it into intervals (probably two $x\in(0,1)$ and $x\in(1,\infty)$), and investigate the inequalities on the intervals, but I am stuck here at the moment.</strike>

UPDATE:

We see that (1) is an odd function, so it sufficient to investigate only one part, e.g. we need to show that for $x\geq 0$,
$$g(x)=(x-1)(x+3)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(x-1)}{3+x^2}\right)\geq 0$$
We see that for $x\geq 0$, the equation has exacly 2 roots, $x=0$ and $x=1$ and therefore we can look at the sign in the subintervals. For example,plugging $x=0.5$, $g(0.5)=1.44022$ and $g(2)=3.909$. Thus the function $g(x)\geq 0$, and therefore $f(x)$ is non-increasing for $x\geq0$ (and by the oddness of (1), non-decreasing for $x\leq 0$).

If we look at the extrema $x=0$, and $x=1$, we see that $f(0)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=0$, therefore $f(0)=\frac{1}{3}$ is global maximum.

Comment: Your 1st equation is very nice. Simplify $f(x) \le \frac{1}{3}$ for $0 \le x < 1$.

Comment: Please check the equation after (1). A '-' is missing in RHS.

Comment: Some typos: In (1), "$\le 0$" is missing. In the denominator of $f'(x)$, it should be $\left(\cos(\frac{2 \pi}{3 + x^2}) - \cos(\frac{2 \pi x}{3 + x^2})\right)^2$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks.

Comment: You forget to edit the equation after (1)? It should be $(x-1)(x+3) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi(x-1)}{3 + x^2}\right) \geq - (x+1)(x-3) \sin\left(\frac{2 \pi(x+1)}{3 + x^2}\right)$.

Comment: In (1), you need to prove that $g(x) - g(-x) \ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$. However, $g(x) \ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$ does not imply $g(x) - g(-x) \ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$, right?

Comment: @RiverLi, Yes, you are right. It does not imply that (as far as I can see). I had the error in the sign, so now I have to think about how to get around it. Go ahead with posting your answer, as it might take longer for me to fix it.

Comment: @RiverLi, I guess we could compare LHS with RHS on subintervals, so e.g. if $g(0.5)>g(-0.5)$ and $g(2)>g(-2)$ then $g(x)>g(-x)$ on $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, but I somehow doesn't like it. Looking forward to your approach.

Comment: Actually my solution is not nice.

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x)=\frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}=1+2\frac{x-1}{3+x^2}$$

$$\text{$g$ is continuous for all real numbers and has a derivative} \\ \text{therefore we can find the max and min} \\ g'=2\frac{3-x^2+2x}{(3+x^2)^2}; \quad g'=0\Rightarrow (x-3)(x+1)=0 \\ \text{After that it's obvious that the range of $g$ is } [f(-1),f(3)]=[0,\frac{4}{3}] $$

$$\text{At $g(2)=1$ the $\tan$ function inside $f(g)$ for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ isn't defined}$$

$$f(g)=\tan\Big(g(x)\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\cdot \tan\Big(g(-x)\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$$
$$g\cdot\frac{\pi}{2} :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow[0,\frac{2}{3}\pi]$$

$$\text{And also, at }x\geq0,\;g(x)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\in[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{2}{3}\pi] \\ \hspace{135px} g(-x)\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$\text{And since when both $tan$ parts of the function when $g(x \geq 0)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{2}{3}\pi]$} \\ \text{are multiplied, we get a negative result,} \\ \text{Therefore we should check for $\forall x\;\;g(x\geq 0)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\in[\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{2})$}$$

$$\text{From here it should be simpler to continue, what you should end up} \\ \text{with is that at $\frac{\pi}{6}$ the $\tan$ functions take their maximal value when} \\ \text{$g(x)\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{6} \;$and multiplied together, the result will be $\frac{1}{3}$}$$

Comment: To be honest the simple methods (integration, theorems...) would have been better.

Comment: this method is better

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer :

Well we can use Jensen's inequality remarking that :

$$f(x)=\ln\Big(\tan\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(1+x)^2}{3+x^2}\Big)\Big)$$

Is concave on $[\frac{-17}{100},\frac{17}{100}]$

So we have :

$$f(x)+f(-x)\leq 2f(0)$$

A bit of algebra and we get the result !

We can improve the reasoning for that we use a substitution:

$$x=\frac{a}{a+1}$$

And follow the same reasoning !

The concavity (an attempt)for $-\frac{17}{100}<x<0$:

We start by introduce a function called $j$ :

$$j(x)=\ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}-1\right)^2}{3+\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^2}\right)\right)$$

The derivative is equal to :

$$j'(x)=-\frac{\pi(4x+3)\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2(4x^2+6x+3)}\right)\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2(4x^2+6x+3)}\right)}{(4x^2+6x+3)^2}$$

Using the substitution $y=4x^2+6x+3$

The function :

$$h(y)=-\frac{\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2(y)}\right)\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2(y)}\right)}{(y)}$$

Is increasing and negative .On the other hand the function :

$$g(x)=\frac{\pi(4x+3)}{(4x^2+6x+3)}$$ is decreasing positive .

So as a multiplication we deduce that the function is negative increasing so the second derivative is positive . $j$ is convex .

We have $j\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=f(-x)$

We Differentiate  and using the fact that :

$k(x)=\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}$ is negative decreasing and $j$ is negative decreasing  we deduce by multiplication that $-f'(-x)$ is decreasing so $f(-x)$ is concave on the interval .

Hope it helps you !

Comment: Can you show how to prove that $f(x)$ is concave analytically? $f''(x)$ looks very complicated.

Comment: @RiverLi there is two possibilities : first use a general form like $f(g(h(x))$ , or use Jensen convexity+continuity but I recognize it's not simple .

Comment: @RiverLi I have improved the reasoning for $0\leq x <\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: You can write down the details if you can prove the concavity.

Comment: @RiverLi I go further but I think it's really bad ! Sorry I shall delete in some hours !

Comment: @RiverLi I stop here but i think that I have proved on the interval above that the function is concave but no more .You're right it's too hard !Thanks for the lucidity.

Comment: I think your proof is nice for the concavity of $f$ on the interval.